# Entity Class doesn't extends base Class properly in Symfony 2.1 and Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I created separate `generalBundle` which has `Model` and `Entity`.My `storeBundle` extends that bundles entity.But

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

command does not create `generalBundle` fields.It creates only `storeBundle`'s extra created fields.I'm not sure where I went wrong can anybody suggest?

My `generalBundle` model class contains

```
namespace ste\GeneralBundle\Model;

use DateTime;

abstract class Share 
{
    protected $id;
    protected $user;
    protected $comment;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }



    public function setComment($comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
    }


    public function getComment()
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }
}
```

My `generalBundle` entity class contains

```
    namespace ste\ActivityBundle\Entity;

    use ste\GeneralBundle\Model\Share as BaseShare;


    class Share extends BaseShare
    {

    }
```

And finally My `StoreBundle` entity class contains

```
namespace ste\StoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use ste\GeneralBundle\Entity\Share as BaseShare;

    /**
     * ste\StoreBundle\Entity\Share
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="shares")
     */
    class Share extends BaseShare
    {
        /** 
         * @var integer $id
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        protected $id;
    }
```

Here `protected $id;` filed is added later as I got Error like

```
No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "ste\StoreBundle\Entity\Share" sub class of "ste\GeneralBundle\Entity\Share". Every Enti  
  ty must have an identifier/primary key.
```

And my `GeneralBundle > Resources> Config >Doctrine` contain file `Share.orm.xml` contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                  http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="ste\GeneralBundle\Entity\Share" table="share">

        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>

        <field name="user" column="user_id" type="integer" />


        <field name="comment" column="comment" type="string" length="255" />


    </entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

No other configuration are done! Any Clues? Something is there to add `DependencyInjection`?

Comment: Does `orm:info` show the missing class?

Comment: Sorry.I don't have idea about that.where sholud i check that?

Comment: It's a CLI command. Probably `doctrine:info` under Symfony 2

Comment: `Doctrine` only this command is there `doctrine:mapping:info`

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking for

Comment: shows everything is Ok

Comment: Yeah, but is the class listed? And why doesn't the `Share` entity have an inheritance map?

Comment: Base class not listed.Your mentioning about `GeneralBundle` Entity `Share` class OR `StoreBundle`'s?

Comment: I'm talking about the abstract share class. It should be listed in your mapped classes: if not, then you should first discover that one.

Comment: Okay.Thanks.I found out.I gave solution in answer.

Comment: How to add relationship One-to-Many Or Many-to-one in Model? OR should we do it in Entity?

Comment: [add relationship One-to-Many Or Many-to-one in Model? OR should we do it in Entity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973226/add-relationship-one-to-many-or-many-to-one-in-model-in-symfony-2-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.I have to add in `config.yml` these lines:

```
orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                   steStoreBundle: ~
                   steGeneralBundle: ~
```

Since it is separate bundle other than `StoreBundle` in my case.